# Sql server bugs? Query result isn't deterministic when group by expression?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following query

```
with cte1 as (
    select isnull(A, 'Unknown') as A,
           isnull(nullif(B, 'NULL'), 'Unknown') as B,
           C
    from   ... -- uses collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS when joining 
    group by isnull(A, 'Unknown'), isnull(nullif(B, 'NULL'), 'Unknown'), C
    ),
    cte2 as (select top (2147483647) A, B, C from cte1 order by A, B, C),
      -- Removing cte2 makes it work if running directly as SQL query. However, 
      -- it still behave the same if the code is in view or table function 
    ctes as (
    .... -- pretty complex query joining cte2 multiple times
         -- uses row_number(), ntile
    )
    select count(*) from finalCTE
```

The result (count) **change every time** when it's executed. And it's much less than the number it should be. I found any one of the following steps can make it right.

1. Materialize (temp or permanent table) the CTE `cte1` and use the materialized table instead.
2. Change the group by in `cte1` to **any** of the following forms.

   - `group by A, isnull(nullif(B, 'NULL'), 'Unknown'), C`
   - `group by isnull(A, 'Unknown'), nullif(B, 'NULL'), C`
   - `group by A, nullif(B, 'NULL'), C`
   - Use `cte1` stead of `cte2` in other CTEs. (**Update:** This step doesn't always work. Still has the problem when it's in a table function, although it works if run the SQL directly)

However, why the original query behave strangely? Is it a bug in SQL Server?

Full function code:

```
ALTER function [dbo].[fn] (@para1 char(3))
returns table
return
with    cte1 as ( select AAA, BBB, CCC
               from     dbo.fnBBB(12)
               where    @para1 = 'xxxx'
               union all
               select   AAA, BBB, CCC
               from     dbo.fnBBB2(12)
               where    @para1 = 'yyyy'
             ),
        -- Tested not using cte2, the same behave
        cte2 as (select top (2147483647) AAA, BBB, CCC from cte1 order by AAA, BBB, CCC),
        t as ( select   e.CCC, e.value1, cte2.BBB, cte2.AAA
               from     dbo.T1 e
                        join cte2 on e.CCC = cte2.CCC
             ),
        b as ( select   BBB, AAA, count(*) count, 
                        case when count(*) / 5 > 10 then 10 
                             else count(*) / 5 
                        end as buckets
               from     t 
               group by BBB, AAA 
               having   count(*) >= 5 
             ),
        b2
          as ( select   t.*
               from     b
                        cross apply ( select    *,
                                                ntile(b.buckets) over ( partition by t.BBB, t.AAA order by value1, CCC )
                                                as bucket
                                      from      t
                                      where     BBB = b.BBB
                                                and AAA = b.AAA
                                    ) t
             ),
        m1
          as ( select   AAA, BBB, b2.CCC, Date, SId, value2, b2.bucket, --
                        _asc = row_number() over ( partition by BBB, AAA, bucket, Date, SId order by value2, b2.CCC ),
                        _desc = row_number() over ( partition by BBB, AAA, bucket, Date, SId order by value2 desc, b2.CCC desc )
                        ,count(*) over (partition by BBB, AAA, bucket, Date, SId) scount
               from     b2 join dbo.T2 e on b2.CCC = e.CCC
             ),
        median
          as ( select   BBB, AAA, bucket, Date, SId, avg(value2) value2Median, min(scount) sCount
               from     m1
               where    _asc in ( _desc, _desc - 1, _desc + 1 )
               group by BBB, AAA, bucket, Date, SId
             ),
        bounds
          as ( select   BBB, AAA, bucket, min(value1) dboMin, max(value1) value1Max, count(*) count 
               from     b2
               group by BBB, AAA, bucket 
             )
    select  m.*, b.dboMin, b.value1Max, Count
    from    median m join bounds b on m.BBB = b.BBB and m.AAA = b.AAA and m.bucket = b.bucket 
    -- order by BBB, AAA, bucket
```

Function used in cte1:

```
CREATE function [dbo].[fnBBB](@param int) 
returns table
return
with    m as ( select   * -- only this view has non default collate (..._CS_AS)
               from     dbo.view1 -- indxed view. 
             )
    select  isnull(g.AAA, 'Unknown') as AAA,
            isnull(nullif(m1.value, 'NULL'), 'Unknown') as BBB
            , m.CCC
    from    m 
            left join dbo.mapping m0 on m0.id = 12
                and m0.value = m. v1 collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
            left join dbo.map1 r on r.Country = m0.value
            left join dbo.map2 g on g.N = r.N
            left join dbo.mapping m1 on m1.id = 20
                and m1.value = m.v2 collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    where   m.run_date > dateadd(mm, -@param, getdate())
    group by isnull(g.AAA, 'Unknown'), isnull(nullif(m1.value, 'NULL'), 'Unknown'), m.CCC
```

Comment: You are using a `TOP` clause without order-by, right?

Comment: @usr I use `Top` and I do have `order by`.

Comment: The order-by is probably not a total order. Maybe it is ambiguous. This allows SQL Server to produce results that differ in order every time. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @usr, I just updated the question. It seems it's related to the order by.

Comment: TOP 100% means nothing. In fact, the optimizer just deletes that. Why is it even there? Let's do an experiment: remove *all* order-by's and TOP clauses. Are the results stable now? I bet they are.

Comment: Actually I changed it to `top (2147483647)` lately.

Comment: Good trick. If the number of rows in that CTE is less than the limit you specified the results should indeed be stable. Any idea why the order-by could matter? The experiment gave evidence that the order-by is the problem. On the other hand it could trigger some other change in the query plan. Maybe you can post it in its entirety?

Comment: @usr Just updated the question. I totally removed the top/orderby part but it still has problem in table function while it works if run directly.

Comment: Ok. This is not a bug in SQL Server. You are relying on undefined behavior somewhere and we have to find out where. The problem persist with all order-by removed so lets look elsewhere. Are you using collations somewhere? ROW_NUMBER or other ranking functions? Please just post everything because that makes it easier to scan for undefined behavior.

Comment: @usr Yes, I use all row_number, ntile, collation (cte1 only) in the query.

Comment: You do realize that there is a difference between ISNULL, IS NULL, etc.?  Reading Technet, I think you maybe running into the condition about using ISNULL is the WHERE  clause..  Have a look here under #C at - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: At the moment I suspect incompletely defined order in an OVER clause, or the grouping operation choosing one of many variants of the same key arbitrarily (e.g. 'a' and 'A'). I'm out for today but you can do some investigations yourself.

Comment: @usr Thanks. I just posted the code.

Comment: May be this bit is different on every run: `where   m.run_date > dateadd(mm, -@param, getdate())`?

Comment: @Stoleg run_date is type of date. The inconsistent results happened in a few minutes. Actually I changed the getdate() to a constant for some testing and it behave the same.

Comment: Maybe you make selection in non-default collation, but grouping is done in default collation?

Comment: Check `CROSS APPLY` bit as well. I'll continue tomorrow.

Comment: Please post the query plan.

Comment: If you think it is a bug post it on Microsoft Connect. Almost certainly it isn't though and you'll be disabused of the notion. I can't be bothered to look at the wall of code and you haven't provided a runnable test case that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @MartinSmith It's write in normal T-SQL and it runs without syntax error. It still behave the same in table function/view after the order by cte is removed (which is questioned by some commenters). Is there any specified reason you think it's certainly not?

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 - Probably 99% of the time on Stack Overflow that people claim to have discovered a bug in SQL Server they haven't and it is working correctly. My first suspicion for undeteterministic behaviour would be duplicate values for one of the `ROW_NUMBER` clauses. for example dupes of `BBB, AAA, bucket, Date, SId, value2 , b2.CCC`

Comment: @MartinSmith I suspected the window function too. However, the columns used in `partition by` and `order by` in the `row_number` function cover the PK. And materialized `CTE1` prevents the issue so it approves that the window functions are fine?

Answer (score 2):

SQL is a set based language. In this paradigm, the order of rows returned is normally not relevant. You can think of unordered as the default behavior. When you actually want rows to be ordered you need to explicitly use ORDER BY somewhere in your query, to specify how to order.

For normal unordered queries the actual order of rows returned by a query may be determined by many things. For example the physical layout of rows on disk, order of index nodes for indexes actually used by query optimizer to return the rows, actual execution order of query plan steps etc - most of which are decided at execution time and may even vary between subsequent executions.

If this is what you are observing this is not a bug at all but a fundamental and normal behavior in all relational database engines.

Comment: I added the `cte2` for forcing a table spooling. However, it behave the same even if it's removed. Materializing `cte1` fixes the the issue, changing grouping by also fixes the issue.